# how can i calculate a slope of the curve of data signal

Tags: matlab

I need help. I have plotted a data double complex, and I want to calculate a curve slope of that data. in my code I calculate a signal_sin and signal_cos that represent my delta_x and delta_y, now I want to calculate a slope of the curve, can someone help me with Matlab code, thank you.

Comment: Please elaborate your question. SO do not mean ready-made code provider. Also I am confused by the term `curve slope`. do you mean slope of a curve?

Comment: Read about function diff......get the successive differences of points and divide it by time step...this gives you slope eh?

Comment: If you have a x and y values, you can simply use  obj=fit(x,y,'poly1'). obj will contain the slope and intercept of the line of best fit.

Comment: I have sin and cos values